# Is it possible to increase the font size for game tips?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Is there a way to increase the font size for the game tips that pop up in the left hand side of the HUD to make it easier to read? Can I also do the same for the game menus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the game does not provide a functionality that would allow you to change the font size of anything, meaning you'll have to rely on mods, which unfortunately cannot be applied to the console version, which is currently the only version in existence.

You could try to lower the `Settings > Display > Safezone Size`, which would move the tooltips more towards the center of the screen, but that doesn't actually change the font size.